# Chained conditional probability, lying and telling truth

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Four witnesses A, B, C, D at a trial each speak the truth with probability 1/3
independently of each other. In their testimonies, A claimed that B denied
that C declared that D lied. What is the (conditional) probability that D
told the truth?

Note: I was told that I can assume, say taking the statement C declared that D lied to mean if C told the truth then D lied but if C lied then D told the truth.

I started by listing out the sample space, but obviously with four witnesses that got large very quickly... So I decided to just list the ones that pertain to the situation described. Here is what I have so far:

(1) D lied, C truth, B lied, A truth

(2) D truth, C lied, B truth, A truth

(3) D lied, C truth, B lied, A lied

(4) D truth, C lied, B truth, A lied

But I don't think these are all the possible sequences. Could someone put me on the right track? I'm getting stumped by the part "B denied"

Comment: Though I haven't found an answer, this seems to be known as *Eddington's Controversy*. http://www.bernardleong.com/2009/05/23/a-mathematical-solution-to-eddingtons-controversy-problem/

Comment: @RandomUser: But the page you link to includes an answer?